# Explanation for Limit of $(b_n)_n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(a_n)_n$  be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $n \geq 2$ there exists an integer $k$ such that $n/2 \leq k < n$ such that $a_n = \frac{a_k}{2}$. Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$.

My question relates to understanding the solution. It states that

> We need to redefine the sequence $(b_n)_n$ such that we have $$ b_n = \max({|a_k|, 2^{n-1} \leq k < 2^n}).$$
> Then it follows that $b_n \leq \frac{b_n-1}{2}$. Hence $0 \leq b_n \leq \frac{b_n-1}{2^{n-1}}$ which implies that $(b_n)_n$ converges to 0. We also have $|a_n| \leq b_n, \text{for } n \geq 1$ to obtain $(a_n)_n$ converges to zero by applying the squeeze theorem.

My question is really about how to obtain $b_n$ and how one could obtain the specific $(b_n)_n$ value, especially with the $2^{n-1} \leq k < 2^n$ being quite "wide"?

Alternative solutions to the question are also welcome.

Comment: Can you fix the typos first?

Comment: Typos? Which part are you referring to?